# Activity needs to be set if initial lifecycle state is resumed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am trying to integrate react-native application inside inside my native android. I Follow steps give following links

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps
https://medium.com/mindorks/react-native-integration-with-existing-app-f2757c2e672d

Here is my react activity code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.
        builder()
        .setApplication(getApplication())
        .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
        .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
        .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
        .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
        .build();
mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "AwesomeProject", null);
setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

But I am getting following error when my react activity get launched

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Activity needs to be set if initial lifecycle state is resumed
        at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:35)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:250)
        at com.skw.android_react_2.MyReactActivity.onCreate(MyReactActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: i'm also facing same issue

Comment: build new simple helloworld application using androidx and try to integrate react application to it

Answer (score 10):

You can fix this in two ways. Either set the activity:

```java
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
    .setApplication(getApplication())
    .setCurrentActivity(this) // <== *** HERE ***
    .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
    .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
    .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
    .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
    .build();
```

...or change the initial life cycle state to something other than `LifecycleState.RESUMED`:

```java
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
    .setApplication(getApplication())
    .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
    .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
    .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
    .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.BEFORE_CREATE) // <== *** HERE ***
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys if you integrating react native application inside native android, please update android studio to latest version and update android plugin and use androidX, androidx jetifire is not helping need to migrate project to androidx